# Upper Bounds Of Sub Sets

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory

> Prove/Disprove:
>   
>   Let $A\subseteq B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ If $B$ is bounded from below so $A$ is bounded from below.

$B$ is bounded from below $\rightarrow$ $x\leq B$.

Let there be $z\in A$, we know that $A\subseteq B$ so $z\in B$ therefore $x\leq z: \forall z\in B$ So $x\leq z$ and $A$ is bounded from below too.

Is the logic correct?

Comment: You are supposed to show that $A$ is bounded from above, not from below. (It is false).

Comment: @ajotatxe sorry, my mistake it is below (edited)

Comment: Yes, the logic is good.

Comment: @gbox, looks good to me! But I will end it this way: .. so $z\in B$, therefore $x\le z,\forall z\in A$

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of not leaving the question unanswered:

It looks good but little correction at the end:

.. so $z\in B$ therefore $x\leq z, \forall z\in A$ and hence $A$ is bounded from below.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is mostly correct; there are a few details that I would include in your proof that may seem trivial, but with mathematical proofs, oftentimes small details are the difference between a right and a wrong answer.

I would say:

Let there be a value $z\in A$. By hypothesis, since $A\subset B$, we know that $z\in B$ as well. If $B$ is bounded below, then there exists a value $b$ for which $b\leq x$ for every $x\in B$. **Thus, we know that $b\leq z$ for all $z\in A$ as well** (in other words, since all of the $z$ values are a subset of the $x$ values, and $b\leq x$ for all $x$, it is only logical that $b\leq z$ for those $x$ values that also happen to be $z$ values). The bolded statement is the definition of a lower bound, so $A$ is also bounded from below.     *Q.E.D.*

Hope that makes sense!